# Binary search 2D array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, multidimensional-array, binary-search

I have been given a programming assignment to create a binary search method for a 2D array that sorts through strings. I'm doing as part of a course that has lots of specifics, I can't use any pre-built search methods. I have been provided a standard Binary search method for a 1D array containing Integers, which is not much help to me.

the code I have below is my best effort but it returns "Game not found!" (even though the game exists in the array).

```
//Write the code for a Binary Search for the Game Title in the 2D array and display the
//information in the other textboxes when found, add suitable feedback if the search is not
//successful(do not use any built-in array methods)

private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int min = 0;
    int max = gameCount -  1;
    int foundIndex = -1;
    bool isFound = false;
    String target = txtGameTitle.Text;
    sortArray();

    if (gameCount == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter game data");
    }

    while (!isFound && !((max - min) <= 1))
    {
        int mid = (max + min) / 2;
        if (string.Compare(gamesArray[mid, 0], target, true) == 0)
        {
            foundIndex = mid;
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (string.Compare(gamesArray[mid, 0], target, true) > 0)
            {
                max = mid;
            }
            else
            {
                min = mid;
            }
        }
    }
    if (isFound)
    {
        lstMyGames.SelectedIndex = foundIndex;
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Game not found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is string only on one row or can it wrap to next row?

Comment: if your 2d array is sorted by row or column then you can use your 1d algorithm on each row or column

Comment: @jdweng from his code it looks like it is a 2d array of string with each string containing an entire title.   If that is not the case he should update the question to be more specific.

Comment: First problem the code is only looking for the string at the beginning of the line since it is using Compare and will only work if the string is exactly the size of the line.  So Contains should be used instead of Compare.  Second problem the code is assuming the array is sorted.  Third the test for the while loop is missing one compare due to <= 1.